# Could a robot be programmed to be human?

Tags: mobile-robot, humanoid

This is all hypothetical. If it was possible, it would have been done by now.

I realise that this area has been touched upon in many sci-fi movies but I wondered that if it was even feasible, how could it be achieved?

I know that it would raise a lot of ethical questions, I don't doubt that but I'm interested in the science.

What would a robot's brain have to be like to function like a human brain? For example, for it to have emotion (e.g. love, empathy), learn new things and remember them, make all those connections that a human brain does?

Thanks to all who reply!

Answer (score 1):

The correct question is "Will humans ever be able to know everything about themselves?" In order to transfer an **exact** copy of A to B you first have to have full knowledge about A especially when it comes to things as complex as the way humans live and think. If at some point in the future humans manage to unravel all the mysteries of the human body and mind, then and only then they will be able to program an machine to behave in the exact same way. Of course this is also restricted by the technologies that one has at his/her disposal. When it come to brute computation power computers already have the upper hand. However when it comes to associative thinking humans are the winners. Another question is if such a thing is necessary/desired? It has been suggested by psychologist that the more human-like a machine looks like, the more troubled people feel in its presence.

Comment: Are you alluding to the [uncanny valley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/uncanny_valley) ? I was under the impression that was still an unproven hypothesis.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I do agree that there is no 100% solid proof for it (will edit my post accordingly) but it is definitely observed by many people.